# Dart, right click mouse event not firing

Tags: event-handling, mouseevent, dart, right-click

When I left click (in dartium) my break point on my listener gets hit, but when I right click it doesn't, have I set up something wrong or is this a known bug?

Dart Editor version 0.6.21_r26639
Dart SDK version 0.6.21.3_r26639

```
html.onClick.listen((MouseEvent event){

  if(event.button == 2){ //left click hits breakpoint on this line - right clicking doesnt

    contextMenu.show(this, left: event.clientX - 5, top: event.clientY - 5);

    contextMenu.html.onMouseOut.listen((Event event){

      contextMenu.hide();

    });

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right clicks are handled with [onContextMenu](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html#onContextMenu).

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oncontextmenu)